# two or more components as one "big" component

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show some information of some objects, let's put an example: cinemas

so, i need 2 or 3 TextView in one "big" component. In this case, first TextView could be cinema name, and secon TextView for the number of films.

I would like to put them like if there was only one, so, onclick events, or while pressing any of them, it would respond like 1 textview (not 2 or 3, with the same sensation of background when you press some button)

is there any way to do this? or just to handle all events i need and fire them for all views?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Extend a LinearLayout to create a Cinema class, and inflate an xml containing 2 textviews, or whatever you want. Handle all the events inside the Cinema class.

An example.

http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/Custom_Progress_Bar/src/com/beanie/example/views/MyProgressBar.java

Answer (score 0):

you can just set an onclicklistener on the layout containing all the buttons/views